# Replace strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, path

I'm creating a program in which I get the path of a file, then send it as a parameter into another program. The problem is when I get the path, it has the special character `'\'`, which completely mess up the string I send to the other program. Is there a way I can ignore the escape character or change it to `'/'`? 
Thanks!!

Comment: have you tried quoting the process argument?

Answer (score 0):

To change the `\` to `/`, a simple iteration over the string should suffice. The required code is:

's' is assumed to be the concerned string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
  if (s[i] == `\`)
    s[i] = `/`;
}
```

Comment: You need to escape '\'

Comment: I was thinking of adding the replace with find as the argument. The only issue was that I was not sure if I needed to call it in a loop or if one call would be sufficient to change all characters. Hence, avoided it. Shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate your question. The problem may be with second program.

First Program may be :

```
char str1[50]="start abc.exe ";
char str2[20];
cin>>str2;
strcat(str1,str2);
system(str1);
```

Second program may be (abc.exe) :

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
 {     
  cout<<argv[i]<<" \n";
 }
}
```

This is just an example.